# Is there a API for the new apple remote app?

Tags: iphone

The new apple remote app on iPhone and iPad is pretty cool. I'm wondering is there a public API to use?

Since the remote app is not a server, so it's not like other "control itunes" apps or programs. I'm wondering is there any API or service exposed on PC/Mac side so that other apps can use it to control itunes?

Ultimately, I'd like to build my own app(on iPhone) or PC program to control the iTunes.

Comment: Given that the Remote app isn't a 'server', it having an API wouldn't make much sense. Perhaps if you could describe what you'd like to do, there might be some answers other than the Remote app having an API

Comment: You're right, the app is not a server, so it's not like other "control itunes" apps or programs. I'm wondering is there any API or service exposed on PC side so that other apps can use it to control itunes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no API, but the protocol used by iTunes, called DAAP, is well understood.  If you don't mind dropping down to handling it directly via the network protocol there are some decent resources that explain it pretty well.  Take a look at:

[Digital Audio Access Protocol (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Audio_Access_Protocol)

[DAAP protocol - Tapjam](http://tapjam.net/daap/)

[TunesRemote: Android DACP/iTunes Remote Control](http://dacp.jsharkey.org/)